# Environment Variable Error when running Python/PySpark script

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Is there an easy way to fix this error:

```
Missing Python executable 'python3', defaulting to 'C:\Users\user1\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\bin\..' for SPARK_HOME environment variable. Please install Python or specify the correct Python executable in PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON or PYSPARK_PYTHON environment variable to detect SPARK_HOME safely.
```

Would I have to modify the `PATH` system variable? Or export/create the environment variables `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` and `PYSPARK_PYTHON`? I have Python 3.8.8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to add an environment variable called SPARK_HOME: this variable contain the path to the installed pyspark library .

In my case , pyspark is installed under my home directory, so this is the content of the variable :

```
SPARK_HOME=/home/zied/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark
```

also you need another variable called  PYSPARK_PYTHON which have the python version you are using like this :

```
PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3.8
```

Comment: @sbati zied: If it is python 3.8.8 would you set still set PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3.8

Comment: yes you can try either python3.8 or python3.8.8 or just python. i think if you are using windows then it needs to be just python (PYSPARK_PYTHON=python)

Comment: Usually, the issue is that the full path to the Python executable contains spaces. That causes pyspark to fail on Windows. Just make sure python.exe is in the PATH, and simply assign PYSPARK_PYTHON=python.exe (append whatever version numbers are necessary) and that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the **path** in your **jupyter notebook** in the following **code** and **RUN IT EVERYTIME**:-

```
import os

os.environ["PYSPARK_PYTHON"] = r"C:\Users\LAPTOP0534\miniconda3\envs\pyspark_v3.3.0"

os.environ["PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON"] = r"C:\Users\LAPTOP0534\miniconda3\envs\pyspark_v3.3.0"

os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = r"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_333"
```

I have gone through many answers but nothing works for me.
But it works in my case. **This has resolved my error**.

Comment: That path is very specific to you on your machine "C:\Users\Laptop...", you might want to make it more generic.